# Php form string modification

Tags: php, forms

I want to make a php form, which takes an URL as input from user and then, adds a block of text to it. 
Example : if a user enters "http://solmri.com/27" in the form, and, the php script adds "?geek" to it.
So, the result the user gets is "http://solmri.com/27?geek" .....
Please suggest a method to do it....

Comment: You mean to say _"How to learn PHP?"_

Comment: You can use this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking about string concatenation in php?

```
<?php
 $a = "URL";
 $b = $a . "geek"; // now $b contains "URLgeek"

 $a = "URL";
 $a .= "?geek";     // now $a contains "URL?geek"
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

as a side note, if you are planning to pass variables using the url you would need to do something like

```
URL?geek=true
```

Comment: I have a doubt... How to take input from user and display output ?

Comment: I did a bit..... The form will look like

<html>
<body>

<form action="stringadd.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>

Stringadd.php looks like this:

<html>
<body>

The URL you requested is : <?php 
$url = "Hello ";
$b = $a . "?geek";
echo $url; 
?>

</body>
</html>

Is it correct?
And also tell me how to redirect user to stringadd.php after submitting the form.

Comment: in stringadd.php you would have to use `$_POST["url"]` . Look at http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php . Based on this you could use something like `<?php $url = "Hello ".$_POST["url"]."?geek" ; echo $url; ?>`

Comment: If you have no problem, can you tell me that how to store the url in a database.... So that it can be used later on..... Thanks in advance....